# Text Overlapping with Figures in Overleaf Document

Tags: overleaf

I'm working on a LaTeX document in Overleaf and am experiencing an issue where the text is overlapping with my figures. Despite using figure placement specifiers, the text that should appear below the figures is rendering on top of them instead.

Here's a brief outline of my document structure where the issue occurs:

`\chapter{UML} % Text content... \begin{figure}[h] \centering \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{path/to/figure.png} \caption{Figure Caption} \label{fig:figure1} \end{figure} % More text content...`

I have tried using [!htb], [!htbp], and even \clearpage before and after the figures. I've also ensured that the figure labels are unique and checked for package conflicts. The issue persists: the text that is supposed to come after the figure appears on top of it.

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
Have the text correctly follow each figure, not overlap.
Ensure figures are placed as close as possible to where they are referenced in the text.
```

Could there be something I'm missing in my figure environment or document setup that is causing this issue?

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre] that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the placement of text and figures in my Overleaf document. The structure in my LaTeX source is organized as alternating text and images, specifically in the order: text – image – text – image. However, in the compiled PDF, the output I'm getting is: text – text – image – image. My expectation is that each block of text will be immediately followed by its corresponding figure. I need the figures to appear close to the text they are related to.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a short, but compilable test file.